# Optimizing Risk defender dice strategy

Tags: probability

In order to improve my newby coding skills, I thought it would be a good idea to implement a piece of code that takes care of a problem that presents itself in the board game Risk. In this game the battles are decided by rolling dice (d6). The rolls of the *attacking player* and *defending player* are ranked and compared to each other. If *attack value* > *defence value*, the defender loses an army. In other cases the attacker loses an army. The attacking player throws three dice. The two dice with highest value are then selected. The defending player may choose to throw either 2 or 1 dice. This is the problem I am interested in. I would like to write an algorithm to determine whether it would be optimal for the defender to use 2 or 1 dice, depending on the throw of the attacker.

First, a quick example of a dice battle, in order to clarify. Attack throws: 1,5,2. Highest values are selected: 5,2. Defender chooses to throw two dice: 4,2. In order to calculate results the corresponding ranks are compared: 5>2, so defender loses 1 army. 2=2, so attacker also loses 1 army.

My idea was to optimize the army losses of the attacker. I would establish the optimum strategy by comparing the expected attacker losses when the defender used one die to the situation where the player used two dice. So roughly the functions looks like this:

Expected attacker loss = <sup>p</sup><sub>lose 2</sub> * 2 + <sup>p</sup><sub>lose 1</sub> * 1 + <sup>p</sup><sub>lose 0</sub> * 0

Now we reach the point where I got stuck: defining the probabilities. This is how far is got, using the probability of attacker loses two as example:

<sup>p</sup><sub>lose 2</sub> = number of combinations * $\frac{x}{6}$ * $\frac{y}{6}$

where:
x = 7 - [attack dice value 1] & y = 7 - [attack dice value 2]

For example, when attacker throws: 5,3. The defender wins when highest value either 5,6 and lower value 3,4,5,6. At first I thought the number of combinations was simply 2, but there are of course 6 combinations (1&1, 2&2 etc) that only occur once. So my first question is: how can I write a function that accounts for the number of combinations?

I am not that schooled in maths and especially not in probabilities. So I am also wondering whether this approach is generally correct. I realise I could also use a brute force method and simulate many games, but I would like to write out the probability functions, if that is possible.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Use MathJax for math formatting-http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: When I was first learning to program I too looked at the probabilities of an attack in Risk. On computers that were orders of magnitude slower than yours, I found it was still practical to brute-force the answer: three dice for the attacker and two for the defender give 7776 equally-likely outcomes, so I separately evaluated the attacker's losses in each of the 7776 cases, added up the results, and divided by 7776. That lets you concentrate on the programming details, such as getting the bounds of iteration and correctly evaluating each case, rather than getting lost in the math.

Comment: [This article](http://datagenetics.com/blog/november22011/) and [this one](http://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~jaosborn/research/RISK.pdf) might be helpful. [This question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-can-i-estimate-my-chances-to-win-a-risk-battle) on Boardgames SE looks like it has some useful pointers, too.